# Can't Port Forward To Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, networking, webserver, portforwarding

I've set up an Ubuntu Web Server to host a game that uses port 25565.
I've set the router to port forward that port to the web server and gave the web server a static local IP. I've done this before using my own PC as the server.
When I try accessing the web server on that port using it's local IP I have no problem at all.
But, when I try accessing it from outside the network, I can't connect.

I've opened my router's list of DHCP clients and the web server is only listed there sometimes without a pattern I've been able to see.

**Why I think the error is at my router:**

I've installed Wireshark on the server to see if Apache was somehow blocking the web packets upon arrival. I tried opening all ports and I tried opening port 10000 which webmin uses (I'm able to connect to it locally). Neither has been successful.
Although I'm not experienced in the field, I don't think the packets get to Apache.

Please assist. Thank you!

Comment: Checked with port check / port forward sites? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=port%20forward%20test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by changing the web interface of the port forwarding from atm1.1 to ppp1.1. It was just luck, as I understood it's web protocols but I don't know why it worked.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Does your router hold the external IP address, or an internal one?

If it holds a private IP like `192.168.x.x`, `10.x.x.x`, or `172.16.x.x`, then you would need to setup port forwarding on whatever device your router is connected to.